# "Красивая" ссылка на Flask

Tags: python, flask

Есть небольшое приложение. В Redis находятся пары ключ:значения по шаблону:

```
 { https://google.com: 73826374 }
 { 73826374: https://google.com }
```

При переходе по этому адресу

```
/?code=73826374
```

Пользователя перенаправляет, соответственно, на гугл.

Вопрос в следующем - как реализовать ссылку для перехода на сайт без `"?code=73826374", дабы она выглядела следующим образом:

```
/73826374
```

Comment: `@app.route('/<int:code>')` вроде бы в любом туториале по фласку должны писать про роутинг, не?

Comment: Благодарю) 
Можете ответ написать не комментарием? Зачту за верный

Comment: Видимо где-то пропустил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен так называемый url-converter (подробнее: https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#url-converters)

Пример:

```py
@app.route('/<code>')
def print_code(code):
    print(code)
```

Однако в таком случае код отработает и для запроса вида `/asd` и `/123`, что не всегда соответствует желаемому результату.
Если вы хотите, чтоб код отрабатывал только для целочисленных значений, вам нужно его немного изменить:

```py
@app.route('/<int:code>')
def print_code(code):
    print(code)
```